# How to get items from Listadapter in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I have a Listadapter wherein there are 4 different strings, and storing them to my listview. Now I want to get all the items from one of those strings and parse it to "date", so how can I able to populate my calendar dates from my listadapter?

Following the codes:

```
  // Get User records from SQLite DB
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList = controller.getAllevents();
    // If users exists in SQLite DB
    if (eventsList.size() != 0) {
        // Set the User Array list in ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CalendarActivity.this, eventsList, R.layout.calendar_event_list, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                TAG_EVENTTITLE,TAG_EVENTSTART,TAG_EVENTEND},
                new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.eventname, R.id.eventstart, R.id.eventend});
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        String eventstart = adapter.toString(); //I got null exception here..

        Date edate = ParseDate(eventstart);

        if (caldroidFragment != null) {

            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.Green, edate);
            caldroidFragment.refreshView();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch an item from your adapter you can use

```
adapter.getItem(position);
```

which will return the item at the specified position. In your case, that method will return the `HashMap<String, String>` at the specified position:

Example:

```
/* adapter.getCount() returns the count of how many items 
   (HashMaps, in your case) that is represented in this adapter. */
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
     HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = adapter.getItem(i);
    //"myKey" is the key that you provided, when mapping your key-values
    String myVal = myHashMap.get("myKey");
    Date edate = ParseDate(myVal);
    /* Handle your Date object here. I'm just printing it to the console
       in this example. */        
    System.out.println("Item at position " + i + " " + edate.toString());
}
```

Comment: I use `  String eventstart = (String) adapter.getItem(2);` it gives an error saying "java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String" how to solve this?

Comment: @JessIanSefulan Check my edit. `adapter.getItem(2)` returns a `HashMap`, not a `String`. You have to get your values from the returned `HashMap`

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'position'. Should I declare it first as an Integer?

Comment: 'Position' is an integer that you specify, e.g. '1' or '2' @Jess Ian Sefulan

Comment: it returns only 1 item? I need to fetch all items in "eventstart" is it possible?

Comment: @Jess Ian Sefulan give me an hour or two, I'll update my answer later

Comment: here's what I want sir, I want to get all the items in "eventstart" and store it to 'edate'. I think I need to loop them in order to store to date right?.

Comment: @JessIanSefulan You are correct, a loop is required. See my update :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Just simply put inside the loop and change the 'position' variable into the variable that handles the loop e.g  `for (int i = 0; i < eventsList.size(); i++)` change `adapter.getItem(position)` to `adapter.getItem(i)`